# How to scrape data that is showing on google map markers

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have done scraping on multiple websites. However, this website seems somewhat different to me, because when I check XHR network tab there are no query parameters attached to request. But I see the response in XHR tab for selected state, district and AC.

http://psleci.nic.in/Default.aspx

After selecting the options, zoom-in to the location I will see following image.

[image: Google Map Location]

After clicking the location point, there is a pop-up dialog with information.

This is the information that I need to scrape for every combination.

Note :

- You might be asking why I haven't paste any code-snippet that I have worked on.
- I am not sure exactly where to start..

Please provide instructions or some idea from where should i start or approach the problem..

Comment: Use selenium web driver